# Reduce not null duplicate rows in MySQL from many to one

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an `update` statement to resolve some issues with duplicates in a table on MySQL. The table structure is shown below. I need a MySQL statement that will set the value of duplicate as `NULL` except the first one, i.e the one with the lowest id. Here the id is the primary key.

This is an example of what I have:

```
 id       name
  1        foo
  2        foo
  3        bar
  4        NULL
  5        NULL
  6        foo
  7        bar
```

This is the desired result:

```
 id        name 
  1        foo
  2        NULL
  3        bar
  4        NULL
  5        NULL
  6        NULL
  7        NULL
```

The table has other columns with useful information. Hence, the row can't just simply be deleted.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: MySQLServer not MS SQL

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
UPDATE t JOIN
       (SELECT name, MIN(id) as min_id
        FROM t
        GROUP BY name
       ) tt
       ON t.name = tt.name and t.id > tt.min_id
    SET t.name = NULL;
```

I think the logic is easier to follow using `JOIN`.  Basically, it says to find the minimum id for each `name`.  Then set all other rows for the same `name` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UPDATE` query can include a `JOIN`.

e.g. join the minimum id for each name and only update where the id is not the minimum.

```
UPDATE
    t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            MIN(id) AS id
        FROM
            t
        GROUP BY
            name
    ) t1 ON t.id = t1.id
SET
    t.name = NULL
WHERE
    t1.id IS NULL
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n3oRpLTHxPLZqLWybSHkDc/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t JOIN
   (SELECT name, MIN(id) as min_id
    FROM t
    WHERE name IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   ) tt
   ON t.name = tt.name and t.id > tt.min_id
SET t.name = NULL;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that the OP can learn from it